Accessing javascript function inside an iframe
There is a website which supplies me some html.
I want to access the functions inside the iframe.
I looked around on the interwebs and found window.frames property that seemed to change whenever i inspect element that iframe.
My problem is I want to do this programatically, in a userscript/js console. I looked at contentWindow but whenever i query the iframe and use contentWindow.somerandomfunction() i get:
Uncaught DOMException: Permission denied to access property "somerandomfunction" on cross-origin object

I never understood how these cross-origin things worked and why the browser can do it but js console can't. *(but it can do it too if i inspect element and then use window.frames.somerandomfunction())
*

When you inspect the element, you also switch the context of the console into the iframe. There is a dropdown with the current context. - You can't access anything within the iframe unless it's on the same domain or it willingly allows access such as by exposing a messaging interface (you can send messages between frames cross-origins but both ends need to support it). This is for security reasons, otherwise somebody could load your bank's website in an iframe and call the "transferMoney" function without your consent. This is totally unrelated to CORS by the way, so I'm removing those tags.

Well what other solution have you thought about? Do i use a mutationobserver and see when window.frames changes ? To be more specific the iframe is a video player

What is the solution to my problem. The iframe is on another domain

If you own the other domain: implement a messaging interface there. If not: talk to the owner of the domain and ask if they would provide this for you. If they don't: no solution, sorry, it's intentionally not allowed without consent of the other domain's owner.
